# How to get data from an sqlite3 prepared statement with 'union all' clause

Tags: c, sqlite

I got three `SELECT` statements connected with `UNION ALL`. I set up the compound statement such that `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` would prepare the resulting rows for me. If I were to make use of the resulting data, could I use a `for()` loop?

```
int i;
for(i = 0; sqlite3_step(res) == SQLITE_ROW; i++) {
    if (i == 0) data1 = sqlite3_column_int(res,0);
    else if (i == 1) data2 = sqlite3_column_int(res,0);
    else data3 = sqlite3_column_int(res,0);
}
```

Is this supposed to work? I've tried it but it gives me garbage data. Is there an alternative way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This works. the garbage data came from somewhere else entirely. You can use this to shorten the amount of code you type but note that there is a limit on how much you can use this.

Additional Info: You can use `UNION` to select from different tables using the same arguments of `WHERE` on each, say you let the user input two data parameters and there are four tables using those parameters, different only by some additional value. Let's say I want to get the value of that additional column. I will let the user type something distinct to the table where my desired output belongs. using `SELECT` statements compounded with `UNION`, one can select the desired output much easier than doing actual comparisons and lengthy iterations.